# Mongo date not access in outside of laravel setup

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5

**I am using jessengers package in laravel setup.**

**I found the date in this form.**

```
"deliver_time" : {
"sec" : NumberInt(1480543565),
"usec" : NumberInt(0)
},
```

**My insert code below.**

```
$data['deliver_time'] = new MongoDate();
Table::insert($data);
```

Please provide me any solution, What can I do to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I had RND about and got correct answer and applied it.

I did update my jessengers package from 3.0 to 2.3 then insert from both side and got same ISO date format.